# Any issue with using update-alternatives to switch python3 to an older version?

Tags: ubuntu, python

I'm wondering if doing this is something that will wreck the entire system, or if it's something that's actually done. We have a server that we're attempting to upgrade, and a lot of our workflows use the command "python3." Right now this means python3.4.

We want to upgrade this system and install the latest python, but not everything has been tested with python3.7 just yet. My plan was to do this:

1. Install python3.7 as well as 3.4.
2. Use update-alternatives to switch python3 to point at 3.4 instead of 3.7.
3. Have everything continue to use python3, except for tasks specifically tested under 3.7, which will be switched to call 3.7 explicitly.

Is this recommended? I've used alternatives to do this sort of thing before but Python I've noticed some strangeness and I want to make sure this is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

(you didn't mention which Ubuntu release you're running, my examples are from 18.04 LTS)

`update-alternatives` only works for packages which use the Debian alternatives system. Those packages invoke the `update-alternatives` command in their maintainer scripts, and have symlinks that point into the `/etc/alternatives` directory.

Looking at python3, we see that it is not a link to `/etc/alternatives`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
```

This symlink is installed by the `python-minimal` package:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/python3 
python3-minimal: /usr/bin/python3
```

If you modify it, then if the `python-minimal` package is upgraded (for example by a security update), it will revert your changes and put the symlink back the way it was.

If you want scripts using `python3` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to invoke a different version of python, you can add a symlink `/usr/local/bin/python3` pointing to your preferred version. Because `/usr/local/bin` precedes `/usr/bin` in the default `PATH`, this should do what you want.